# OleDBReader returning System.Data.Oledb.OleDbDataReader instead of the values

Tags: c#, sql, database, object, reader

I currently have some problems returning some fields out of my database into my Listbox.

The text I get returned is System.Data.Oledb.OleDbDataReader instead of the items I want out of my database.

```
        private void lbzoektermen_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\martijn\Dropbox\Proftaak Periode 2 Identity\Database11.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();


        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * from Zoekcriteria";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            lbzoektermen.Items.Add(reader);
        }
        connection.Close();
```

Should I use the Overwrite Tostring method for this? I'm kind of confused

Kind Regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an index to reader in order to get one of the fields. E.g. if you want the first field, change loop like this:

```
if(reader.HasRows)
{
    lbzoektermen.Items.Add(reader[0]);
}
```

Comment: If I do that it says that there are no values in the row, so I guess that there is something wrong with my Query than?

Answer (score 0):

The below code line is wrong cause you are adding the returned reader object to listbox item collection whereas you should be attaching the reader object to the `DataSource` property of your listbox control

```
lbzoektermen.Items.Add(reader);
```

It should rather be

```
lbzoektermen.DataSource = reader;
```

You might also want to invoke `DataBind()` method on `lbzoektermen` control if it's a `ASP.NET` application.

Per your comment, since you are using a listbox control you need to add a single item. You need to change your query and select a specific column you want to add to control like

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * from Zoekcriteria";
```

Change to

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT columns1 from Zoekcriteria";
```

Comment: Still gives the same results as Lbzoektermen.Items.Add(reader);

Comment: If I try to do that it crashes at the OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

The error message says that there are parameters missing

Comment: What parameter? you are not passing any parameter to your query. Is it your actual code? If not then post the actual code.